# Unable to fetch labels from Loki (404 page not found ), please check the server logs for more details

Tags: grafana-loki

Installed Grafana, Loki and promtail using loki-stack helm chart to an AKS cluster. Due to specific client requirement grafana is installed with prefix path as /grafana and Loki is installed with http_prefix_path as /nwloki. I am able to login to grafana. But the default loki datasource is giving below error while testing.
“Unable to fetch labels from Loki (404 page not found ), please check the server logs for more details”

Loki service URL http://loki:3100 is working
curl http://loki:3100/nwloki/metrics. is working
curl http://loki:3100/nwloki/ready is working (readiness and liveness)
curl http://loki:3100/nwloki/loki/api/v1/push is working
curl http://loki:3100/nwloki/api/v1/status/buildinfo is working

But
curl http://loki:3100/nwloki/loki/api/v1/labels are giving 404

Grafana Version: 9.5.1
Loki and Promtail Versions: 2.8.1

Loki values.yaml is as below

loki:
enabled: true
isDefault: true
rbac:
pspEnabled: false
nodeSelector:
environment: grafana
image:
tag: 2.8.1
persistence:
enabled: true
config:
table_manager:
retention_deletes_enabled: true
retention_period: 720h
server:
http_path_prefix: /nwloki/
extraArgs:
server.path-prefix: /nwloki/
url: http://{{(include “loki.serviceName” .)}}:{{ .Values.loki.service.port }}
readinessProbe:
httpGet:
path: /nwloki/ready
port: http-metrics
initialDelaySeconds: 45
livenessProbe:
httpGet:
path: /nwloki/ready
port: http-metrics
initialDelaySeconds: 45
datasource:
jsonData: “{}”
uid: “”

Any idea why the labels are not available?

Tried using lower versions of grafana and loki. Still same issue

Comment: I believe this is due to an open issue when using a path prefix: https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/4756